# Unable to upgrade to Plasma-desktop 5.18

Tags: plasma-5, 20.04, kde5

I upgraded my system from ubunut 18.04 -> 19.10 -> 20.04.
I have plasma-desktop(5.12) running in 18.04 version now I want to upgrade to 5.18

When I run `sudo apt update & sudo apt upgrade` its showing

> All packages are up to date.

If I run `sudo apt install plasma-desktop` I am getting

> plasma-desktop is already the newest version (4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1).

output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: I'm confused. In your first sentence, you have one system which you've upgraded, somehow, from 18.04 to 19.10 and now to 20.04. But in the next sentence you write about "plasma-desktop(5.12) running in 18.04 version". Are you referring to the same system as in the first sentence? If so, is your problem that plasma-desktop is still stuck at 5.12 rather than being 5.18.4?

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd. plasma 5.12 is ancient compared to 20.04. The cause is likely due to another package requiring explictly an old version of plasma. That package is likely old and unmaintained.

in comparison, here is the unique version number I have installed on my freshly upgraded system

```
mathieu:~ :-) (lifebook-wu2) $ apt search plasma | grep installed | grep -o "[: ]5[^a-z]\{6\}" | sort -u

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

:5.17.5-
 5.18.4.
:5.18.4.
 5.68.0-
:5.68.0-
mathieu:~ :-) (lifebook-wu2) $
```

5.17 is a single them package I have `plasma-look-and-feel-org-kde-breezedark-desktop`

5.18.4 being plasma related package
5.68 is the KDE Framework

====

I recommend you scan for those 5.12 packages and see if you can remove them.

it will tell you which package keeps requiring it.

you should be able to clean this up.

hope it helps.
please post which package you ended up removing for future reference for others

cheers,